# Error when trying to alter column type

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I have an existing `DATETIME` column in SQL Server 2016. I need to write a DDL script to change it to `DATE` type.

When I run the following script, I get an error message. Not sure how do I fix it...

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA];

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] 
    ALTER COLUMN myDate DATE;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA];
```

Error message:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The object 'PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA' is dependent on column 'myDate'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 2
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN myDate failed because one or more objects access this column.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "dbo"."TBL_MyTable"
(
     column1,
     myDate datetime NOT NULL,,
     column2,
     column3,

     CONSTRAINT PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA 
         PRIMARY KEY (column1, myDate, column2, column3)
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA 
    ON "dbo"."TBL_MyTable" (column1, myDate, column2, column3)
GO
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to `ALTER` two tables, or did you forget to obfuscate your table name in all three statements in your example?

Comment: First of all: if you're specifying your constraint names yourself, **make them USEFUL** - don't use these cryptic system-generated names! Also: that unique index is **totally useless** since you've already defined the PK on the same columns - the PK **by definition** is unique - no use in creating a second unique index on these columns

Answer (score 0):

I'd create the `DATE` column as a new column, populate it, then drop the `DATETIME` column.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] ADD MyDateCol DATE
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable]
SET MyDateCol = CAST(myDate AS DATE)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] DROP COLUMN myDate
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA ON [dbo].[TBL_MyTable]
(
  column1,
  MyDateCol,
  column2,
  column3
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA];

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] 
    ALTER COLUMN myDate DATE not null;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MyTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__TBL__3F4E83EE204C47AA] Primary Key
(
  column1,
  MyDate,
  column2,
  column3
)